# Calculate the acceleration of the trailing muon bunch

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, acceleration

Two separate suitably short but intense [bunches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charged_particle_beam#bunch_structure) of [muons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon), "A" and "B", are both supposed to be constantly accelerating (in an otherwise sufficiently flat region) with constant proper acceleration vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ (as measured by any system of participants who are mutually at rest) in the same direction and co-linearly (let's say "A leading in front", and "B trailing behind"), but not necessarily equally accelerated (therefore acceleration vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ don't necessarily have equal magnitudes).

Meanwhile the muons of both bunches decay, with equal and constant proper [mean lifetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_lifetime#Mean_lifetime) $\tau_{\text muon}$, and correspondingly with equal proper "half-life duration Log[ 2 ] $\tau_{\text muon}$".

Also, the two bunches are separated such that they always "remain in sight" of each other; such that

- B (or some suitable accompanying instrumentation) always finds that it takes 1 half-life from "stating a ping" until "observing A's reflection", while
- A always finds that it takes 2 half-lives from "stating a ping" until "observing B's reflection".

Question:
What's the magnitude $| \bf b | $ ?
Can it be calculated at all, in terms of "mean lifetime $\tau_{\text muon}$" and "speed of light $c$", based on the described setup conditions?

(Surely the described setup conditions are consistent with bunches A and B being called "rigid to each other", or having been "ends of a rigid rod", in the sense of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67037/is-it-possible-to-have-uniform-proper-acceleration-along-a-large-object-without) and [that question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/extended-rigid-bodies-in-special-relativity) and the various comments there.

My question is intended to obtain illustrations of different approaches to the "rigid rod" problem which were indicated in those comments; even if they obtain the same answer value.)