# Determining the stability of a clock, flying with a rocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, experimental-physics, equivalence-principle

A rocket is flying straight along, with constant acceleration. It has a ground floor whose acceleration magnitude is $\mathbf a_g$, and directly above it has an upper floor (let's assume: a transparent upper floor, made of safety glass) which is accelerating with magnitude $\mathbf a_u < \mathbf a_g$, [of course](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38377/an-accelerating-and-shrinking-train-in-special-relativity/63110#63110).

On board there's a clock, $\mathfrak C$, which is quite thin and which runs as specified when being laid on any surface (even when lying face-down).

When put on the ground floor clock $\mathfrak C$ always runs at a certain rate, $\nu_{\mathfrak C g}^{\,}$; and when placed on the upper floor (let's assume: face-down) it always runs at a certain faster rate, $\nu_{\mathfrak C u}^{\,}$; namely: $$ \nu_{\mathfrak C u}^{\,} = \left(\frac{\mathbf a_g}{\mathbf a_u}\right) \, \nu_{\mathfrak C g}^{\,}.$$

(Of course, an astronaut $A$ sitting on the ground floor who watches the ticking clock $\mathfrak C$ as it lies face-down on the transparent upper floor determines his receiving rate of the tick signals, $\nu_{A g}^{(\circledR \, \mathfrak C u)}$, as being larger than rate $\nu_{\mathfrak C u}^{\,}$; namely: $$ \nu_{A g}^{(\circledR \, \mathfrak C u)} = \left(\frac{\mathbf a_g}{\mathbf a_u}\right) \, \nu_{\mathfrak C u}^{\,} = \left(\frac{\mathbf a_g}{\mathbf a_u}\right)^2 \, \nu_{\mathfrak C g}^{\,}.$$)

**Question (homework-and-exercise problem):**

Is clock $\mathfrak C$ stable
(considering it being placed alternatingly on ground floor or upper floor as described; and disregarding possible instability as it is transported between floors) ?

And as far as clock $\mathfrak C$ is not exactly stable, quantify its instability.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure: the setting in OP question _"when placed on the upper floor [...] it always runs at a certain faster rate"_ was inspired by the assertion of C. W. Chou, D. B. Hume, T. Rosenband, D. J. Wineland, [_"Optical Clocks and Relativity"_](https://www.google.com/search?q="optical+clocks+and+relativity") (2010), Fig. 3 (A): _"As one of the clocks is raised, its rate increases when compared to the clock rate at deeper [position]."_.

Comment: Gravitational time dilation is not the ratio of proper accelerations.

Comment: @g s: _"Gravi. time dilation is not the ratio of proper accelerations."_ -- Correct; and the (geometric-kinematic) relations between two clocks (and additional participants) which are being held rigidly wrt. each other in a curved region **are not exactly the same** as the (geometric-kinematic) relations between two clocks (and additional participants) which are being held rigidly wrt. each other in a flat region. By the equivalence principle, **they are related**; and indeed: the nearer to being equal the closer the ratio of proper accelerations (of the clocks in the flat region) is to $1$.